# Python ast Libary - retreive value of Node inside a function call

Tags: python, abstract-syntax-tree

Follow up question of here: [Python ast Libary - how to retreive value of a specific node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73739633/python-ast-libary-how-to-retreive-value-of-a-specific-node)

I use the following code to retreive `{'console_scripts': ['main=smamesdemo.run.main:main']}`

import ast

```
code = '''extras_require={"dev": dev_reqs}
x = 3
entry_points={
    "console_scripts": ["main=smamesdemo.run.main:main"]
}'''

for node in ast.walk(ast.parse(code)):
    if isinstance(node, ast.Assign) and node.targets[0].id == 'entry_points':
        expr = ast.Expression(body=node.value)
        ast.fix_missing_locations(expr)
        entry_points = eval(compile(expr, filename='', mode='eval'))
```

This works fine, but this example had a reduced complexity.

My real life example is a Python Package where I want to retrieve this values:

As minimal as it can be it looks like this:

```
import ast

code = '''extras_require={"dev": dev_reqs}
if __name__ == "__main__":
    setup(
        entry_points={
        "console_scripts": ["main=smamesdemo.run.main:main"]
        }
    )
'''

for node in ast.walk(ast.parse(code)):
    if isinstance(node, ast.Assign) and node.targets[0].id == 'entry_points':
        expr = ast.Expression(body=node.value)
        ast.fix_missing_locations(expr)
        entry_points = eval(compile(expr, filename='', mode='eval'))

print(entry_points)
```

Wrapping a function call around this will make the `ast.Assign` node disappear?! From my understanding, I would just get one more Node, but this is not the case.

Why does this happen and how get I retreive the desired values inside such a structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case the value of the desired dict comes from a keyword argument, so you should look for an [`ast.keyword`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.keyword) node instead of an `ast.Assign` node:

```
for node in ast.walk(ast.parse(code)):
    if isinstance(node, ast.keyword) and node.arg == 'entry_points':
        expr = ast.Expression(body=node.value)
        ast.fix_missing_locations(expr)
        entry_points = eval(compile(expr, filename='', mode='eval'))
```

Demo: https://replit.com/@blhsing/VividDarlingPhysics

Comment: thank you so much. Never had a Topic in python before where I struggled as hard as with this